# ESP32 / SD Card: reading attributes of files in sufolders

Tags: c, file, esp32

I am writting a GPS and other sensor program. The exact application is not that important. What I want to do is write the logging data to a SD Card. Using an ESP32, I finally managed to connect the SD module using the mySD files - using example called "nanosdcard" https://github.com/nhatuan84/esp32-micro-sdcard. This allows me to access all the card details (card type, volume size, etc.). It is very difficult finding examples that allow you to assign your own connection pins like what is necessary on an ESP32 - Arduino wiring is standard, and appears to be hard coded into the SD files.

Using the example found here https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=348562.0, I am able to make sure that any files written to the SD Card have the current and modified date and time stamps. I have written a filename generator function that uses the following format: YMMDDHHs.ext. The "s" is a sequence number from 0-9, so I can generate up to 10 unique files in an hour, while being limited to the 8.3 file name size. The time stamp is a nice extra.

Using the example found here https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=38150.0, I am able to list the files and print out the creation and modification date and time stamps. I also added some other stuff like formatting, fle type and file sizes. I tally up the file sizes (using block sizes) to give me a very rough estimate of space used - probably not accurate, but indicative.

Using another example from the above referenced one - called "nanosdcard1", similar to this http://www.iotsharing.com/2017/05/how-to-use-arduino-esp32-to-store-data-to-sdcard.html, I can scan through a SD Card that contains subfolders and the code prints out the files, folders and file sizes.

One thing I noticed is that the "nanosdcard" file uses what seems to be mySD.h references, but "nanosdcard1" uses SD type references (as if it is referening the standard SD.h file (SD.h is not an include file)).

I modified the "printDirectory" function to call my own "PrintAccessData" funtion, which takes the filename from printDirectory and accesses all the file atribute stuff. The "printDirectory" function is recursive and once it finds a subfolder, it calls itself again. Again passing the filename as a parameter to my "PrintAccessData" function.

Everything works well when the files are only in the root folder. But things don't work when the PrintAccessData needs to print out the details of the files in the subfolders.

The problem seems to be in the "if (!file.open(&root, cFileName, FILE_READ))" call. Checking in mySD shows that the call should be "open(const char *filename, uint8_t mode = FILE_READ)". The file cannot be opened, so the error "file.open failed" is printed.

Using the SD type referencing, I can open a file using a full pathname e.g "TXT/12345.TXT" and read the contents. I can also write to the file, so that is not a problem. The main goal is achieved.

However, try as I might, I cannot get the file to open with the above command (the mySD type commands). I have tried:

- Hard coding the filename and path, with and without a leading "/"
- Software generated path from the entry found when the code finds a folder, also with and without a leading "/"
- Using char arrays (as indicatd by the parameter definition) or Strings as parameter (both works for root, but not sub folder)

It seems like there is some missing reference to the file within the subfolder preventing it from opening. Once the file has been opened (like the root files), then the dir_t struct can be populated and the various attibues read.

**I'm stuck on opening a sub-folder file.**

It is not a train smash that all the log files are in the root folder, but it would be nice to store different file types in different folders - I have made provision for identifying the file extention - the usual - txt, csv, dat, xls, doc, htm. The folder list could get very long.

The code works as is, but I would really like it to be more versatile / generic.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**The PrintDirectory function.** File dir is passed from a "SD.open("/")" call.

```
void PrintDirectory(File dir, byte numTabs) {      // nanosdcard1.ino
  long iFileSize = 0;
  long iSizeTally = 0;
  int iFileCount = 0;
  
  // Begin at the start of the directory
  dir.rewindDirectory();
  
  while(true) {
    File entry = dir.openNextFile();
    if (!entry) {
      // no more files
      //Serial.println("**nomorefiles**");
      break;
    }
    for (byte i=0; i<numTabs; i++) {
      Serial.print("  ");                           // we'll have a nice indentation
    }
    // Print the 8.3 name
    char *cFileName;            // Create a pointer char variable - for the FileName
    cFileName = entry.name();   // Assign the first entry of entry.name() to the FileName pointer created
    Serial.print(cFileName);

    // Recurse for directories, otherwise print the file size
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
      Serial.println("/");
      sPathName = entry.name();

// The way the creation and modification data is retrieved means that reading data from subfolders is not possible at this stage.
// The header file indicates *filepath, but I cannot get the code to recognise any conbination of filepath to open the file

      PrintDirectory(entry, numTabs*2);             // This is the recursion occurs

    } else {
      // Files have sizes, directories do not
      // Display the date and time values, then file sizes
      PrintAccessData(cFileName, sPathName);
      Serial.print(F("\t"));
      if (entry.size() > 1024*1024) {               // > 1 MB
        Serial.print(entry.size()/1024.0/1024.0, 2);
        Serial.println(F(" MB"));             
      } else if (entry.size() > 1024) {             // > 1kB
        if (entry.size() > 102400) {                // > 100 kb
          Serial.print(entry.size()/1024.0, 0);
        } else {
          Serial.print(entry.size()/1024.0, 2);
        }
        Serial.println(F(" kB"));      
      } else {                                      // bytes
        Serial.print(entry.size(), DEC);
        Serial.println(F(" bytes"));
      }
      // Files file complete blocks of 512 bytes even if smaller than 512
      iFileSize = int(entry.size()/512)*512;        // Number of whole blocks
      if (entry.size()%512 > 0) {                   // Any partial blocks
        iFileSize += 512;
      }
      iSizeTally += iFileSize;
      iFileCount++;
    }  
    entry.close();
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Estimated total disk usage: "));
  if (iSizeTally > 1024*1024) {                     // > 1 MB
    Serial.print(iSizeTally/1024.0/1024.0, 2);
    Serial.print(F(" MB"));
  } else if (iSizeTally > 1024) {                   // > 1 kB
    if (iSizeTally > 102400) {                      // > 100 kB
      Serial.print(iSizeTally/1024.0, 0);
    } else {
      Serial.print(iSizeTally/1024.0, 2);
    }
    Serial.print(F(" kB"));
  } else {                                          // bytes
    Serial.print(iSizeTally, 0);
    Serial.print(F(" bytes"));
  }
  Serial.print(F(" ("));
  Serial.print(float(iSizeTally)/iVolumeSize, 3);
  Serial.print(F("%"));
  Serial.print(F(")"));
  Serial.print(F(" in "));
  Serial.print(iFileCount);
  Serial.println(F(" files"));
}
```

**The PrintAccessData function.** I have added quite a few file.close() and root.close() call because the program seems to need that in order to pen up the next file for attribure reading.

```
boolean PrintAccessData(char *cFileName, String sPath) {
  byte bFileTypeLen = 0;                            // Length of the extension name to help align the size numbers later

   // open the root directory
  if (!root.openRoot(&volume)) {    
    Serial.print(" openRoot failed");
    file.close();
    root.close();
    return false;
  }

  // open a file
  if (!file.open(&root, cFileName, FILE_READ)) {     // Probably need to change &root to point to the next location / directory. Does not work with path/file
    Serial.print(" file.open failed. Can't handle subfolder calls\t\t");
    file.close();
    root.close();
    return false;
  }

  dir_t d;
  if (!file.dirEntry(&d)) {                        // Test with a folder name?
    Serial.println("file.dirEntry failed");
    file.close();
    root.close();
    return false;
  }
   
  Serial.print("\t");
  file.printFatDate(d.creationDate);
  Serial.print(" ");
  file.printFatTime(d.creationTime);
  Serial.print("\t");
  file.printFatDate(d.lastWriteDate);
  Serial.print(" ");
  file.printFatTime(d.lastWriteTime);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(GetFileExtension(cFileName, bFileTypeLen));

  for (byte i=0; i<(22-bFileTypeLen); i++) {  // "Comma Separated Values" is the longest file name at 22 characters. Adjust if required.
    Serial.print(F(" "));
  }

  file.close();
  root.close();
}
```

Program output is as follows:

```
* Connecting to WiFi .. connected
  IP address: 192.168.1.2
* Contacting to Time Server ... connected
  Now is : 2020-12-16 16:19:05
* Initializing SD card...
  Card type: SD2
  Volume type is FAT32
  Volume size: 1932.08 MB, 1.887 GB
  ... successful
  No valid filename generated   **Disabled for now, or else it generated a new file every run**
* Files on SD Card: 
  Name          Date Created        Date Modified       Type                    Size
  01210110.CSV  2020-12-15 10:21:48 2020-12-10 11:18:44 Comma Separated Values  58 bytes
  01210111.CSV  2020-12-15 10:21:48 2020-12-10 11:18:48 Comma Separated Values  58 bytes
  01210112.CSV  2020-12-15 10:21:48 2020-12-10 11:18:50 Comma Separated Values  58 bytes
  01210113.CSV  2020-12-15 10:21:48 2020-12-10 11:18:54 Comma Separated Values  58 bytes
  01210114.CSV  2020-12-15 10:21:48 2020-12-10 11:18:58 Comma Separated Values  58 bytes
  01210180.TXT  2020-12-15 10:21:50 2020-12-15 09:14:28 Text File               1.96 MB
  01210181.TXT  2020-12-15 10:21:50 2020-12-15 09:15:02 Text File               106 kB
  01210191.TXT  2020-12-15 10:21:50 2020-12-15 09:15:02 Text File               56.64 kB
  01210192.TXT  2020-12-15 10:21:50 2020-12-15 09:15:02 Text File               566 kB
  01210195.TXT  2020-12-15 10:21:50 2020-12-15 09:15:02 Text File               5.53 MB
  01211080.TXT  2020-12-15 10:21:52 2020-12-15 09:15:04 Text File               4.35 MB
  01211081.TXT  2020-12-15 10:22:26 2020-12-15 09:15:04 Text File               4.35 MB
  01213150.TXT  2020-12-15 10:22:26 2020-12-15 09:15:06 Text File               4.35 MB
  01213160.TXT  2020-12-15 10:22:26 2020-12-15 09:15:06 Text File               81.05 kB
  01215110.CSV  2020-12-15 10:22:26 2020-12-15 11:38:28 Comma Separated Values  152 bytes
  01215111.CSV  2020-12-15 10:22:26 2020-12-15 11:39:54 Comma Separated Values  14.84 kB
  01215112.CSV  2020-12-15 10:22:26 2020-12-15 11:43:38 Comma Separated Values  14.84 kB
  01215113.CSV  2020-12-15 10:22:26 2020-12-15 11:45:32 Comma Separated Values  14.84 kB
  01215114.CSV  2020-12-15 10:22:26 2020-12-15 11:46:44 Comma Separated Values  14.84 kB
  Estimated total disk usage: 21.40 MB (0.011%) in 19 files
  ...done!
```